# How do I get an updated post-sort TableModel?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have a JTable using `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)` and a RowSorterListener attached, per below, because I need to perform some operations elsewhere in my application upon a sort of the JTable.

I find that whenever I click a column header to sort, the JTable redisplays the rows in the proper order and the listener is called, but the TableModel I pull out is always the original pre-sort table model.

```
table.getRowSorter().addRowSorterListener(new RowSorterListener() {
  @Override
  public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent rsevent) {
    rsevent.getSource().getModel(); // Nope, original ordering here
    table.getModel(); // Same thing
  }
};
```

How do I get the new post-sort ordering of the rows, as is now displayed in the JTable?

Comment: How are you initializing the RowSorter in the JTable?

Here's a comment I noticed on DefaultRowSorter:
"DefaultRowSorter is an abstract class. Concrete subclasses must provide access to the underlying data by invoking setModelWrapper. The setModelWrapper method must be invoked soon after the constructor is called, ideally from within the subclass's constructor. Undefined behavior will result if you use a DefaultRowSorter without specifying a ModelWrapper"

Comment: I think you can use table.convertRowIndexToModel(int ...), however I think that there's a better solution available.

Comment: I'm doing nothing other than `table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)`. According to Oracle's JTables tutorial: "This action defines a row sorter that is an instance of javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter." so I don't think I need to manually initialize it at all?

Comment: @Lazy If the method in your second comment will work, please post as answer! Even if there is a "better solution", all valid solutions should be answers and "better" can be judged by votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data in the TableModel never changes, only the view of the data changes.

If you want the data from the model in the order it is displayed in the table then you just use:

```
table.getValueAt(row, column);
```

In other words you need to iterate through all the rows and columns to get the data in the currently viewed order.

Comment: +1 THis is a good example of the distinction between _model_ and _view_.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use table.convertRowIndexToModel(int ...), however I think that there's a better solution available.

If you define your own convertRowIndexToModel() that's a quick lookup (perhaps through a map, O(1)), that solution should be sufficient. If it's O(n), then that's what needs to be fixed.

Simply go through a loop of the rows, convert each one and do the lookup using the resulting index.

Here's 2 methods in TableSorter that should be of interest:

```
 private Row[] getViewToModel() {

    if (viewToModel == null) {
        int tableModelRowCount = tableModel.getRowCount();

        viewToModel = new Row[tableModelRowCount];

        for (int row = 0; row < tableModelRowCount; row++) {
            viewToModel[row] = new Row(row);
        }

        if (isSorting()) {
            Arrays.sort(viewToModel);
        }
    }

    return viewToModel;
}
```

and:

```
private int[] getModelToView() {

    if (modelToView == null) {
        int n = getViewToModel().length;

        modelToView = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            modelToView[modelIndex(i)] = i;
        }
    }

    return modelToView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know this is a really late answer, but I tried the code used on the comment of @LazyCubicleMonkey and it did work here is my code in getting the row when the jTable is sorted.

```
DefaultTableModel search_model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
search_model.removeRow(jTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row));
jTable.setModel = (search_model)
```